# How can I make by default accordion to make open first element?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I use bootstrap accordion in my project.

Here is working [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/68gk8/237/) .

Here is HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="isOpen">
                      <uib-accordion-heading>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <strong>{{group.title}}</strong>
                        <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isOpen}"></i>
                    </div>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
      {{group.content}}</uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])

app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1"
  }, {
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2"
  }, {
    title: "Dynamic Group Header - 3",
    content: "Dynamic Group Body - 3"
  }];
});
```

I tryed to use this row:

```
  is-open="true"
```

Like that:

```
  <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups"  is-open="true">{{group.content}}</uib-accordion-group>
```

But it opens by default all items.

How can I make by default accordion to make open only first element?

P.S. Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OYgWAinuIaYelKUkYAKw?p=preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do take use of `$first` of `ng-repeat` directive to open only 1st accordion like `is-open="$first"`

**Markup**

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
  <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" 
     ng-repeat="group in groups" 
     is-open="$first">
       {{group.content}}
  </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

[**Preview Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tyCquVHzNZFmHMbsf7DV?p=preview)

Comment: Pankaj I am sorry I made some mistake when I wrote question.I updated my question please view it.

Comment: @Michael I don't see any change in what you are expecting? you wanted to open first accordian by default correct. So that what I did.. do look at the plunkr please..

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that arrow stop to react when panel opens or closed.

Comment: @Michael I don't see any arrow.. that might be there in your actual implementation. could you reproduce the problem in plunkr, so that I can help you further..

Comment: @Michael here you go.. I know `ng-init` isn't prefererable still look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/angO9PjsTqsWiybYtAf6?p=preview)

Comment: any idea how to add datatables inside accordion?