# How to open accordion tab on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, accordion

I want to open tab on page load by default.  Right now it is collapsed and to open accordion tab I have to click on the button.  I do not want to click on button every time to open the tab.

```
<div><p-accordion >
  <p-accordionTab  header="Add  Detail" >
    <add-details [state]="'addNew'"></add-details>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
</div>
```

Pulled from comment:

> open]= true it is not working Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'open' since it isn't a known property of
>   'p-accordionTab'. 1. If 'p-accordionTab' is an Angular component and
>   it has 'open' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If
>   'p-accordionTab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'
>   to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of
>   this component. ("`<div><p-accordion >`

Comment: Add the logic whatever you do in your button click, inside `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook.

Comment: either what xyz said, or you add an `Input() open` property in your PAccordionTabComponent and then call it with `<p-accordionTab  header="Add  Detail" [open]="true">`

Comment: I dont have any button it is accordion button ..I have not written any code for that

Comment: [open]= true it is not working Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'open' since it isn't a known property of 'p-accordionTab'.
1. If 'p-accordionTab' is an Angular component and it has 'open' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-accordionTab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<div><p-accordion >

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this to me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/37092876/125981 but the markup here differs a bit so I did not vote it that way.

Comment: Please add what you have tried that perhaps did not work (or add a detailed note to the question for each attempt)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough code to provide a complete and tested answer, but basically what you want to do is apply an ID to the accordion with the # syntax (#accord), then use the ViewChild decorator in your code to provide a variable reference to that accordion, and then call the open() method on that reference in your OnInit method.

Something like this:

```
<div><p-accordion #accord>
  <p-accordionTab  header="Add  Detail" >
    <add-details [state]="'addNew'"></add-details>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
</div>
```

Then in your variable definitions:

```
  @ViewChild('accord')
  private accord: Accordion;
```

And in OnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accord.open();
    // or this.accord.tabs[0].selected = true;
}
```

I'm not sure the exact syntax for Accordion - I'm assuming you're using PrimeNG Accordion however you haven't stated that, so it's hard to solve  your problem exactly, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

If you console.log("this.accord: ",this.accord); you'll get all the methods and attributes for the Accordion and can hopefully find the exactly one you need to use to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open first tab by default, then add `activeIndex="0"` in the the main parent element. In above case it would be like this

```
<p-accordion #accord activeIndex="0">
    <p-accordionTab  header="Add  Detail" >
    <add-details [state]="'addNew'"></add-details>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Note: Grabbed from [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=20841)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header I" [selected]="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header II">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
            architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
            voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi.</p>
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header III">
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati
                    cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
                    Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus.</p>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

You can use `[selected]="true"` for any `<p-accordionTab>` that you want to be opened default ([1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html))

Comment: That's a nice PrimeNG accordion demo, but please include at least a snippet of your code in the answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30503807)